# Typescript module resolution paths

Tags: typescript

I have a folder structure like so:

`projectRoot
├── src
│   ├── app.ts
├── node_modules
│   └── foo
│       └── src
|          |__ foo
|             |__ foo-code.ts`

And in app.ts I have an import which I was to look like this:

`import fooCode from "foo/foo-code";`

As far as I understand from the docs, I should be able to achieve this with something like the following tsconfig:

`{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "."
    },
    "paths": {
        "*": [
            "src/*"
        ],
        "foo/*": [
            "node_modules/foo/src/foo/*"
        ]
    }
}`

However upon compiling I get an error

`error TS2307: Cannot find module 'foo/foo-code'`

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay turns out there were a few issues:

1) I was running tsc with a file specified, which according to the docs, means tsconfig is ignored!

2) Paths should have been inside compilerOptions

3) A better path resolution strategy would have been

        `"paths": {
            "*": [
                "*",
                "src/*",
                "node_modules/foo/src/*"
            ]
        }`